# how to combine 3 complex data frames in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have 3 pandas data frames named df1, df2 and df3

```
df1:
      match_up        result
0   1985_1116_1234      1
1   1985_1120_1345      1
2   1985_1207_1250      1
3   1985_1229_1425      1
4   1985_1242_1325      1

df2:
  team_df2       win_df2  
0  1207           0.700               
2  1116           0.636               
3  1120           0.621               
4  1229           0.615                
5  1242           0.679                

df3:
    team_df3       win_df3  
1   1234           0.667               
7   1250           0.759               
11  1325           0.774               
12  1345           0.742               
15  1425           0.667
```

I need a `new_data_frame` combining `df1`, `df2` and `df3` in following format:

```
          match_up        result  team_df2  team_df3  win_df2  win_df3
    0   1985_1116_1234      1      1116       1234    0.636     0.667
    1   1985_1120_1345      1      1120       1345    0.621     0.742
    2   1985_1207_1250      1      1207       1250    0.700     0.759 
    3   1985_1229_1425      1      1229       1425    0.615     0.667
    4   1985_1242_1325      1      1242       1325    0.679     0.774
```

How to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'match_up':['1985_1116_1234','1985_1120_1345','1985_1207_1250','1985_1229_1425','1985_1242_1325'],
                    'results':[1,1,1,1,1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'team_df2':[1207,1116,1120,1229,1242],
                    'win_df2':[0.700,0.636,0.621,0.615,0.679]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'team_df3':[1234,1250,1325,1345,1425],
                    'win_df3':[0.667,0.759,0.774,0.742,0.667]})


df1['match_up'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])

final = pd.merge(df1,df2,
        left_on=df1['match_up'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1])).values,
        right_on='team_df2',how='left')

final = pd.merge(final,df3,
        left_on=df1['match_up'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('_')[2])).values,
        right_on='team_df3',how='left')
```

Output:

```
In [23]: final
Out[23]: 
         match_up  results  team_df2  win_df2  team_df3  win_df3
0  1985_1116_1234        1      1116    0.636      1234    0.667
1  1985_1120_1345        1      1120    0.621      1345    0.742
2  1985_1207_1250        1      1207    0.700      1250    0.759
3  1985_1229_1425        1      1229    0.615      1425    0.667
4  1985_1242_1325        1      1242    0.679      1325    0.774
```

Comment: `left_on = df1['match_up'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1])).values` what is this function doing here?

Comment: @MJP it breaks up the matchup key by splitting it into a list using '_' as a delimiter.  Then it takes the second value ([1]), which is the key for the first pd.merge.

Comment: why should we specify `right_on`, because already we are specifying `how =left` which says to consider only the keys in left data frame. then what is the need for `right_on`

Comment: "right_on: Columns from the right DataFrame to use as keys. Can either be column names or arrays with length equal to the length of the DataFrame"  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

Comment: Ok got it!! your solution is so elegant and easy to understand.

Comment: When I apply this on my real data frame(problem set). I am getting an error `TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)` what would be the reason?

Comment: @MJP That's what the .values is for.  Basically, it takes a series and makes it a numpy array.

Comment: Hi Liam, I know the previous question was a stupid one, it was a mistake in my code, sorry about that. The above code works fine when the year is 1985.but when the team value repeats(that is for the upcoming years 1988,1986, 1987) there comes the problem. I want to just club these 3 data frames considering the year values as well. I am trying to form the training data set for the basket ball problem :). I am a newbie to pandas, so please help me.  I am trying to form a data frame something like this  https://statsguys.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/slide1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to extract the strings and convert the to ints in order to `merge` correctly...

```
# Set up result DataFrame
df = df1.copy()
df['year'], df['id2'], df['id3'] = list(zip(*df['match_up'].str.split('_')))
df[['id2', 'id3']] = df[['id2', 'id3']].astype(int)

# Do merges
df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='id2', right_on='team_df2')
df = pd.merge(df, df3, left_on='id3', right_on='team_df3')

# Drop unneeded columns and print
df = df.drop(['id2', 'year', 'id3'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

yields

```
         match_up  result  team_df2  win_df2  team_df3  win_df3
0  1985_1116_1234       1      1116    0.636      1234    0.667
1  1985_1120_1345       1      1120    0.621      1345    0.742
2  1985_1207_1250       1      1207    0.700      1250    0.759
3  1985_1229_1425       1      1229    0.615      1425    0.667
4  1985_1242_1325       1      1242    0.679      1325    0.774
```