# Combining Pandas data frames by numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have 3 pandas data frames named `df1`, `df2` and `df3`.

```
df1:
      match_up        result
0   1985_1116_1234      1
1   1985_1120_1345      1
2   1985_1207_1250      1
3   1985_1229_1425      1
4   1985_1242_1325      1
5   1986_1116_1430      0
6   1986_1250_ 1229     0
7   1986_1207_1437      1 

df2:
  team_df2       win_df2  
  1207           0.700               
  1116           0.636               
  1120           0.621               
  1229           0.615                
  1242           0.679
  1116           0.742
  1207           0.567
  1250           0.342                 

df3:
    team_df3       win_df3  
     1234           0.667               
     1250           0.759               
     1325           0.774               
     1345           0.742               
     1425           0.667
     1229           0.845
     1430           0.434
     1437           0.123
```

The column `team_df2` in data frame `df2` is the values succeeding the varaible `year_`(1985_) in data frame `df1`. The column `team_df3` is the value  after the variable `year_val1_`(1985_1116_])

The first 5 rows in the `df2` and `df3` represents the year 1985 and last 3 rows in the data frame `df2`  and `df3` represents the year 1986.

I need a new_data_frame combining df1, df2 and df3 in following format:

```
   match_up        result  team_df2  team_df3  win_df2  win_df3
0   1985_1116_1234      1      1116       1234    0.636     0.667
1   1985_1120_1345      1      1120       1345    0.621     0.742
2   1985_1207_1250      1      1207       1250    0.700     0.759 
3   1985_1229_1425      1      1229       1425    0.615     0.667
4   1985_1242_1325      1      1242       1325    0.679     0.774
5   1986_1116_1430      0      1116       1430    0.742     0.434
6   1986_1250_ 1229     0      1250       1229    0.342     0.845
7   1986_1207_1437      1      1207       1437    0.567      0.123
```

I have previously this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978794/how-to-combine-3-complex-data-frames-in-pandas/28979051?noredirect=1#comment46209663_28979051), I also got a very good answer. but the problem that I am facing is, when the year value changes(in data frame `df` in `match_up` column) the team value in `team` column in `df2` and `df3` keeps on repeating. so if I merge these three data frames on `team_df3` and `team_df2` values I am not getting the desired out put.

So kindly help me with this. operation is equal to combining the data frames 1, 2 and 3 in the image below. but the `match_up` column value in third data frame in image below changes as follows:

A_515_729
.
.
.
B_767_890 
.
.
.
P_390_789

[image]

Comment: It would probably make sense to add the year columns to df2 and df3 so that the year could be used as an additional column to perform the merge on to avoid this ambiguity

Comment: You are recently asking many questions, which is perfectly fine, but I'd like to let you know that it is easier answering the questions if you offer the python code to create the dataframes, rather than copy & pasting their contents. This way one could directly work on the solution instead of (hesitating to) create the dataframes first.

Comment: @Nras - The code is of 30-40 lines. thats why I didnt copy and paste it. I am working on a project and I am working alone on that.

Comment: @EdChum but again I have to drop the year column from the final data frame right?

Comment: You can drop after if necessary but I think you need it to avoid this ambiguity, also having a column containing multiple identifiers is a very bad idea

Comment: @EdChum ok then I will go with you. but how do I add it in front of `df2` and `df3` and merge it. I am still confused with the process. It would be great if your could write an answer using this approach.

Comment: @EdChum shall I provide the entire code? for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your match_up column so we get year and the other df ids as separate columns:

```
In [23]:

df['year'] = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[0])))
df['team_df2'] = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[1])))
df['team_df3'] = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[2])))
df1['year'] = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[0])))
df2['year'] = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[0])))
df
Out[23]:
         match_up  result  year  team_df2  team_df3
0  1985_1116_1234       1  1985      1116      1234
1  1985_1120_1345       1  1985      1120      1345
2  1985_1207_1250       1  1985      1207      1250
3  1985_1229_1425       1  1985      1229      1425
4  1985_1242_1325       1  1985      1242      1325
5  1986_1116_1430       0  1986      1116      1430
6  1986_1250_1229       0  1986      1250      1229
7  1986_1207_1437       1  1986      1207      1437
```

Now we can merge using year and the team columns to avoid the ambiguity:

```
In [24]:

merged = df.merge(df1, left_on=['year', 'team_df2'], right_on=['year','team_df2'])
merged = merged.merge(df2, left_on=['year', 'team_df3'], right_on=['year','team_df3'])
merged
Out[24]:
         match_up  result  year  team_df2  team_df3  win_df2  win_df3
0  1985_1116_1234       1  1985      1116      1234    0.636    0.667
1  1985_1120_1345       1  1985      1120      1345    0.621    0.742
2  1985_1207_1250       1  1985      1207      1250    0.700    0.759
3  1985_1229_1425       1  1985      1229      1425    0.615    0.667
4  1985_1242_1325       1  1985      1242      1325    0.679    0.774
5  1986_1116_1430       0  1986      1116      1430    0.742    0.434
6  1986_1250_1229       0  1986      1250      1229    0.342    0.845
7  1986_1207_1437       1  1986      1207      1437    0.567    0.123
```

You can then drop the columns you are no longer interested:

```
In [27]:

merged.drop('year',axis=1)
Out[27]:
         match_up  result  team_df2  team_df3  win_df2  win_df3
0  1985_1116_1234       1      1116      1234    0.636    0.667
1  1985_1120_1345       1      1120      1345    0.621    0.742
2  1985_1207_1250       1      1207      1250    0.700    0.759
3  1985_1229_1425       1      1229      1425    0.615    0.667
4  1985_1242_1325       1      1242      1325    0.679    0.774
5  1986_1116_1430       0      1116      1430    0.742    0.434
6  1986_1250_1229       0      1250      1229    0.342    0.845
7  1986_1207_1437       1      1207      1437    0.567    0.123
```

Comment: Hi EdChum, I tried to implement your solution. but I get `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` . when I assign `df1['year'] = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[0])))` . so in that case what should I do?

Comment: If the lengths don't match then you could merge it but I'm guessing that df1 in my code is in fact df2 in yours, this may mean you are missing year information in df2, what you could do is add the year information by merging it something like `df1.merge(df, on='team_df2', how='left')`

Comment: Ok I am working on it right now. will let you know after I apply it to my code!!